# Pick a specific day of the week and start counting forward until a set limit is reached in php

Tags: php

Having a php challenge with dynamically setting a day of the week say -thursday, to a function and have the function loop through each day (friday, saturday.. tuesday until a condition i>0 is met. 
I have searched thoroughly but could not finding a matching solution.

Please see break down below:

---

**My form:**
[showing user input that's counted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMzLX.png)

**My code:**

```
//get duraiton in days

function durationInDays($data) {

    $startDate = date_create($data['startdate']);

    $endDate = date_create($data['enddate']);

    $dateDiff = date_diff($startDate,$endDate);

    $durationInDays = $dateDiff -> format("%a");

    return $durationInDays;
}

//pass duration in days to function to break into weeks and days

function numberOfWeeksAndDays($durationInDays) {
    $days = $numdays%7;
    $weeks = floor($numdays/7);

    return [$weeks, $days];
}


//parse in number of days into function to loop starting from 
//day of week of start date say --thursday for example with a 
//condition to stop loop once numberOfDays is zero.

function extraMassCount($dayOfWeek, $numberOfDays, $countMass) {

        $daysOfTheWeek = [
                            'monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday',
                            'monday','tuesday','wednesday','thursday','friday','saturday','sunday'
                         ];
        $massCountForExtraDays = 0; 

        for ($i = $numberOfDays; $i > 0; $i--) {        

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='monday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[0];

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='tuesday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[1];

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='wednesday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[2];

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='thursday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[3];

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='friday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[4];

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='saturday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[5];

            if($daysOfTheWeek[$i]=='sunday')
                $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[6];

        }

        return $massCountForExtraDays;

    }
```

**The problem**: If $numberOfDays=6,then i=6 and the function starts with friday which is not the start date.

**My question**: how do I implement dayOfWeek parameter so the function extraMassCount will start counting dynamically e.g thursday if startdate is thursday and not the way it is hardcoded to start? I hope my question is clear.

That is, as shown in the form, the function is supposed count the number of masses checked per day and add them together. Starting from startdate to the enddate. Once the durationInDays is broken down to weeks and days I need the function to start at the startdate say --wednesday and add countMass(which is a count of the Masses checked by the user with datatype int) for each day onward.. thursday, friday, etc. –  I appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't understand what the function is supposed to do. Please explain more clearly. Are you trying to count, for example, the number of tuesdays in a given number of days? What does Mass have to do with this? What is `$countMass`, it appears to be an array of numbers, but what is this?

Comment: Thanks @jmarkmurphy. As shown in the form, the function is supposed count the number of masses checked per day and add them together. Starting from startdate to the enddate.

Comment: Thanks @jmarkmurphy. As shown in the form, the function is supposed count the number of masses checked per day and add them together. Starting from startdate to the enddate. Once the durationInDays is broken down to weeks and days I need the function to start at the startdate say --wednesday and add countMass(which is a count of the Masses checked by the user with datatype int) for each day onward.. thursday, friday, etc. I hope it's clearer

Comment: That is much clearer, you should now edit that into your question as comments can go away, and that would leave the question unclear again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, with relative date formats and DateTime class

```
$Date = new DateTime;

//go to monday
$Date->modify('monday this week');


for($i=0;$i<10;++$i){
    echo $Date->format('l')."\n";
    $Date->modify('+1 days'); //go to next day
}
```

Output

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/720e27094b72fb3ab5d63153b15613af2731e657)

I think the rest you can work out as I am not really sure what that does.

If you want a number for the day, for like this part `$countMass[0];`  you can use the `w` format.  But `0` is Sunday, if I remember correctly.

```
for($i=0;$i<10;++$i){
   $Date->modify('+1 days');
   //dont assume your inputs will be correct
   if(isset($countMass[$Date->format('w')])){
      $massCountForExtraDays += $countMass[$Date->format('w')];
   }
}
```

PS. instead of all these separate if statements, which is bad performance wise.  I would just use a switch statement, but at the very least connect those with `else` so they don't all evaluate every time, needlessly.  `$daysOfTheWeek[$i]` can only equal one of those.  If you notice above, I just optimized them out.

Comment: Thanks a gazillion, you're the best, you're a lifesaver!